# Use alignas to align struct

Tags: c++, memory-alignment, alignas

In the following struct:

```
struct alignas(?) test
{
    int32_t f1; // 4 bytes
    int8_t f2; // 1 byte
    int8_t f3; // 1 byte
};
```

How to use `alignas` so that `sizeof(test)` would be exactly 6 bytes?

`alignas(1)` is not accepted by compiler (gcc, msvc, clang) (error like: `error: requested alignment is less than minimum alignment of 4 for type 'test'`).

UPD. This variant works OK, of course:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)

struct alignas(?) test
{
    int32_t f1; // 4 bytes
    int8_t f2; // 1 byte
    int8_t f3; // 1 byte
};

#pragma pack(pop)
```

But is there a way to do it without preprocessor using only standard C++11/14?

Comment: What are the required members? Currently your three members will always add up to 6 bytes

Comment: @NickStrupat currently `sizeof(test)==8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `alignas` only lets you make alignment stricter, and only up to the maximum alignment of standard types.

The standard provides no mechanism for misaligning types.